# How to find records 2 years from a created date stored in the individual record

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help in writing an MS SQL query to delete all data in a table, 2 years or more from when it was originally added. `created_date` is stored as `datetime` field type.

Table: **users**

```
user_id
user_name
created_date
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: Have a look at the `dateadd` function and use it with your _created_date_ column

Comment: SELECT *
  FROM [database].[dbo].[users] where created_date < DATEADD(year,-2,GETDATE()) this is what I have but I want the data 2 years from the created_date not todays date.

Comment: From the _created_date_ of which row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM <your_table> WHERE created_date < DATEADD('yy', -2, getdate())
```

Comment: Note I want the date from the date stored in the created_on field in the table  not todays date

Comment: Can't see that you mentioned a `created_on` field in your question

Comment: was just an example, thanks. Have rewarding even though I had the answer was going mad looking at too many windows.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
  FROM [database].[dbo].[users] where created_date < DATEADD(year,-2,GETDATE())

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question, which is identically to my answer?

Comment: Yes I must be going mad!